# Laravel Eloquent : Has many delete, need to refresh

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a strange problem, I have two table : Users and Companies, it's a has many relation :

```
 public function companies() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Company');
 }
```

I have delete on cascade in my companies table:

```
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
```

But now I have a strange problem, for some reason when an user want to create a company. I create it when he click the "add" button and return the edit form (because I need to have an id to attach pictures, etc.)

So if the user click on "create company" and quit the page, I have an empty row in my DB.

So in my user company index I do :

```
public function company_index() {
    $user = auth()->user();

    foreach ($user->companies as $company) {
      if($company->name == "")
         $company->delete();
    }
    $companies = $user->companies;

    return view('front.users.company')->withCompanies($companies);
}
```

My company with empty name is correctly delete in my DB but `$companies = $user->companies;` still get it. If i refresh it's work.

My question is : 
Why `$companies = $user->companies;` still get the companies I delete just before and how can I fix this ?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you want to validate the create company user input to prevent bad data from being inserted

Comment: @morph No, like I explain in my post, i have no create form.

Comment: You can do `if($company->name == ""){
$user->companies->forget($company);
$company->delete();}` !!

Comment: @Maraboc Thanks, it's the simple way to dit. Please post it in answer so I can validate it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove an item from a collection just use `forget` like this :

```
foreach ($user->companies as $key => $company) {
    if($company->name == ""){ 
        $user->companies->forget($key);
        $company->delete();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Dessauges check the update i edited you suggested edit :)